# Extract range regular expression in awk

Tags: regex, awk

I need to apply two conditions in an awk script. In each condition, I want to extract range of number from the column.

Let the data example:

```
14.201
14.10
13.3
9.5
10.600
3.74
4.62
6.89
5.90
11.12
7.11
12.53
8.89
8.965
```

# condition one: where I want to extract any number between 3- and 6 (i.e. 3,4,5,6) and regardless what number after the the '.'

```
$1 ~/^[3-6]\..*/
```

This condition seems to work, however, I'm struggling with the second condition:
where the range between 7-14.

```
$1 ~/^[7-14]\..*/
```

The above gives an error ( because the max would be 9. [0-9]).

Any suggestion how to do the 2nd condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arithmetic comparisons, not regular expressions:

```
$1 >= 7 && $1 < 15
```

Comment: The reason why I'm using regex because I want to include the numbers after the '.' as they are changing over the whole data.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Could you give an example where the regular expression would work but this answer doesn't?

Comment: Notice that since you want anything beginning with `14.`, I used `< 15`, not `<= 14`.

Comment: I'm not saying is not working, I was just wondering how to do it with regex. Thank you.

Comment: And the answer is that this is not really an appropriate use of regular expressions. Vasili Syrakis's answer will work, but it's obviously more complicated than this. If the range were something like `8-1234` it would get even more complicated.

Comment: You could just cheat and use http://rahulchoubey.com/Offline/RangeREGEX.aspx ... because screw actually figuring that range out by hand. `^([0]*)([8-9]|([1-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9]{2})|((123[0-4])|(12[0-2][0-9])|(1[0-1][0-9]{2})))$`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `^[7-14]\..*` fails, is because it is matching `7-1` and then `4`.

In fact, the character class is totally invalid, because `7` comes before `1`.

---

You need to do this:

`(?m)^(?:[7-9]|1[0-4])\..*$`

This is a non-capturing group which contains an alternation between `7-9` and `10-14`.
If the first match fails, it will try the second.

I also specified that ^$ match at line breaks `(?m)`, because it was failing without it on my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and some of regex from Vasili this seem to do the job:

```
awk '/^([7-9]|1[0-4])\./' file
14.201
14.10
13.3
9.5
10.600
11.12
7.11
12.53
8.89
8.965
```

But `Barmars` solution is better.